# Fetch JSON data from Web API and display in HTML table using node JS and Express framework

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, express

I am trying the code written in node JS with express framework but it does not print the output in HTML table.

here is my code written in node with express framework

In **Index.js**

```
const express=require("express");
const app=express();
const port=process.env.PORT||30060
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use('/index',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index"));
     let data;
     
      return res.render("index",{
        data:data
      });
    })
```

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    request('https://test.com/API_v1.0/getuserlist', { json: true }, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        res.render('index', { data: body });
    });
});
```

```
 app.listen(port,()=>{
       console.log(`Server is working on Port number${port}`);
   })
```

and in **index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSON Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Update</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% if (data && data.length) { %>
            <% data.forEach(function(row) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= row.OBJECTID %></td>
                    <td><%= row.name %></td>
                    <td><%= row.email %></td>
                    <td><button class="update-btn" data-id="<%= row.OBJECTID %>">Update</button></td>
                </tr>
            <% }); %>
            <% } %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.update-btn').click(function() {
            const id = $(this).data('id');
            // perform update action
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It print only header of the table in the Web browser and not print the data from Web API

Output :

**Id  Name  Age Update**

Please help to display data in the browser

Comment: Logging `body` to see what shape it actually has would probably be a good start.

Comment: **Danger!**: [The `request` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) was deprecated **three** years ago and you should not use it.